# Meaning of "likelihood ratio criterion is distribution free"

Tags: maximum-likelihood, factor-analysis

This is in ref to pp. 54-55 in [McDonald,R.P (1985)](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Factor_Analysis_and_Related_Methods.html?id=kCLNJnuZQbQC) [1] in the context of exploratory factor analysis (EFA) estimation: I am confused as to the meaning of:

> "(the likelihood ratio criterion) is a distribution free measure of
>   "misfit" of the estimated parameters to sample correlation".

Is it the LRC that is distribution free (isn't it chi-square distributed?) or is it no distribution assumption is being made about the variables being modeled (isn't supposed be multivariate normal).

I am also not clear about the subsequent sentence:

> ...it is a direct measure of the departure of correlation matrix of
>   the residuals from an identity matrix...

I find the book full of insights explained to statistically unsophisticated like me, which is why I am keen to find out what it is that I am missing.I am relatively new to inferential statistics and my grasp on all this is bit tenuous, so apologies if the question is badly worded.

[1] Roderick P. McDonald (1985),
*Factor Analysis and Related Methods*,
Psychology Press

Answer (score 4):

What is meant by a procedure/criterion being distribution-free is that - whatever the distribution from the data were drawn* - the result (in this case, the LRC criterion) has the same distribution under the null.

* (there can be some conditions; often many of the more traditional distribution free procedures require continuity and iid)

"Distribution-free" doesn't mean that the test statistic or criterion can't have a given distribution (in fact, it typically means that it *does*).

The claim being made in the text there is that -- irrespective of what distribution you started with  -- the likelihood ratio criterion (presumably the thing it's calling $Q*$ on the previous page) has (at least asymptotically) the same chi-square distribution.

So yes, normally you have a multivariate normal assumption for EFA -- but the text is saying that if it had some other distribution, the result would still have a chi-square distribution (in the null case).

The point is that in sufficiently large samples the distribution of the calculated result doesn't depend on what distributional model that was. In that sense, it could be said to be (asymptotically) distribution free.

[However, I'm not sure that the earlier claim (p54) about least squares requiring the normal assumption is accurate; unless I mistake something about the situation - which I might, since I don't have the whole document -  I think asymptotically it is also distribution free in a similar sense -- but note that "least squares" isn't a statistic, so it may depend on what the actual statistic is being taken to be.]

Comment: Ta. Understood the answer once the penny dropped about null refers to hypothesis and not the model. Any explanation of the subsequent sentence?

Comment: @enjays sorry I am at a loss there because you made a statement rather than asked a question -- I don't know what part is giving you trouble. You gave a fairly clear indication of where the confusion was in the first case (and in any case, some potential for confusion can be seen in the original), but for your second, you're basically stating "I don't understand X", which gives me nothing to work with (what to talk about at what level -- do I write three paragraphs explaining what a correlation matrix is, for example, or what an identity matrix is?). Please ask a direct question, if you can.

Comment: In respect of the lack of reference to "the null hypothesis" -- originally I wrote exactly that phrase a bunch of times but on more closely reading your reference, because the text there was repeatedly referring to it as a "crtierion" rather than a "test" I felt I should try to avoid painting it too strongly in hypothesis testing terms.

Comment: The likelihood ratio criteria, to me, seems to be performing dual role: I. Providing a measure to determine the probability that the sample is from a population that conforms to the model II. Providing a measure of discrepancy between the model based estimated (population) correlation matrix and the sample  correlation matrix – this discrepancy calculated in terms of straight forward discrepancy between corresponding cells entries in the two matrices.1. (I) is justified by Wilk’s theorem and does not depend on assumption of normality (in point 3 in pg 55, it says “assuming normality . Why?

Comment: 2. What links (I) and (II)? Grateful for reference, preferably elementary/conceptual level

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be requesting a simple clarification of the answer but appears to be asking a new (and fairly extensive) question, even down to requesting additional references.

Comment: posted Q2 as a new question.